# Comparing a nullable column throws "Unable to cast the type..." exception

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

My entity `NewsItem` has a nullable foreign key property: `LibraryID` of type `int?`.

My issue is when I query the property and compare it with any value except `null`, I get exceptions.

Initially my code was:

```
int? lid = ...
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => n.LibraryID == lid);
```

but it gives me no results at all, no matter what `lid` is.

So, I tried:

```
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => n.LibraryID.Equals(lid));
```

gives exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

and then I tried:

```
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => lid.Equals(n.LibraryID));
```

and got:

> **Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.**

and this:

```
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => object.Equals(lid, n.LibraryID));
```

gives same exception as the last one.

Now I was desperate, so I tried to complicate stuff (like other forums suggested, for example [here](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title#suggestion-1015361)):

```
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => (lid == null ? n.LibraryID == null : n.LibraryID == lid));
```

but still getting same exception.

So... any **SIMPLE** workarounds?

Comment: What type is LibraryID?

Comment: EF has no (i congress, limited) support for the Equals method however your first approach should work. Have you validated the actual data you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, that first snippet should work. I've used nullables like that many times. First thing I'd do is a sanity check just to make sure `LibraryID` is really `int?` and not `long?` or similar.

Other than that, you can try this:

```
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => (lid.HasValue ? n.LibraryID == lid.Value : !n.LibraryID.HasValue));
```

Or to avoid the `?:` within the query:

```
var results = lid.HasValue 
    ? context.NewsItems.Where(n => n.LibraryID == lid.Value)
    : context.NewsItems.Where(n => !n.LibraryID.HasValue);
```

Comment: The compiler SHOULD throw an exception if you are trying to compare types that are not equal.  That said, it isn't a bad idea to check that the nullable int has a value, though I'd do it before I even begin the query.

Comment: ok, I verified that all the types that i compare are `int` or `int?`. I tried both of the suggestions but the results returned are not correct. All the records where `LibraryID` is `null` are retrieved no matter what is the value of `lid`.

Comment: My mistake, forgot to put outer brackets around the `? :` so it produced wrong query. The first suggestion works. Now I have to go and change 256 times in my code where I'm using it... ugh...  @p.s.w.g - Thank you!

Comment: @ShayNissel glad to hear it

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => lid.HasValue ? lid.Value == n.LibraryId.Value : (!n.LibraryId.HasValue) );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN docs (which I finally found), .Where() will only filter your collection.  If you want to see if there are actually results, resolve by lazily executing the filtered query with .ToList(), GetEnumerator, or enumerating the collection with foreach;

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its
>   GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For
>   Each in Visual Basic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx

```
int? lid = ...
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => n.LibraryID == lid).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = context.NewsItems
    .Where(n => n.LibraryID.HasValue && n.LibraryID.Value == lid.Value );
```

edit:

Previous filter was based on my understanding that you wanted to filter to entires having a particular value.  Updated will filter to null or value.

```
   var results = context.NewsItems
        .Where(n => !n.LibraryID.HasValue || n.LibraryID.Value == lid.Value );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that EF does not find the correct operator overload. Therefore it produces wrong results if you set `lid = null`.

Use linq to objects by adding `AsEnumerable()` to your query and everything is fine:

```
var results = context.NewsItems.AsEnumeryble().Where(n => n.LibraryID == lid);
```